# Wait until div is not visible to process next line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write some code which is supposed to wait until a predefined `div` is no longer visible in order to process the next line. I plan on using `jQuery( ":visible" )` for this, and was thinking I could have some type of `while` loop. Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to accomplish this task?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".scroller-right" ).mouseup(function( event ) {
        alert('right');
        pollVisibility();
    });
});

function pollVisibility() {
     if ($(".mstrWaitBox").attr("visibility")!== 'undefined') || $(".mstrWaitBox").attr("visibility") !== false) { 
            alert('inside else');
            microstrategy.getViewerBone().commands.exec('refresh');       
     } else {
              setTimeout(pollVisibility, 100);
     }
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".scroller-right" ).mouseup(function( event ) {
        alert('right');
        pollVisibility();
    });
});

function pollVisibility() {
     if (!$(".mstrWaitBox").is(":visible")) {
        alert('inside if');
        microstrategy.getViewerBone().commands.exec('refresh');     
    } else {
        setTimeout(pollVisibility, 100);
    }
}
```

`div` when not visible:

```
<div class=​"mstrWaitBox" id=​"divWaitBox" scriptclass=​"mstrDialogImpl" dg=​"1" ty=​"edt">​
</div>​
```

`div` when visible:

```
<div class=​"mstrWaitBox" id=​"divWaitBox" scriptclass=​"mstrDialogImpl" dg=​"1" ty=​"edt" visibility="visible">​
</div>​
```

Comment: Without knowing the context of your problem, I'd say it's better simply edit whatever code is making div visible and have that "process the next line".

Comment: [Deferred.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Comment: Unfortunately its not that sample, I am extending the functionality of a very large BI application. The javascript which controls this div is very hidden and all the methods are pretty unreadable. At some point the divs viability is changed to visible, I can invoke a custom method at this time using the above code. I need to wait until the div is no longer visible to invoke my next line

Comment: how are you hiding that "div" ? if you are using jQuery to hide it then you can define callback that are execute when hiding its done, see api.jquery.com/hide/‎

Comment: I am not hiding the div. There is some native javascript code which is performing that action. I cannot extend the functionality of that method unfortunately. But the native javascript is toggling the visibility

Comment: Please see my updated answer, it will solve your problem.  You don't need a `while` loop, instead, use `setTimeout` to recursively poll the visibility of the div you are interested in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `setTimeout` function to poll the display status of the `div`.  This implementation checks to see if the div is invisible every 1/2 second, once the div is no longer visible, execute some code.  In my example we show another div, but you could easily call a function or do whatever.

http://jsfiddle.net/vHmq6/1/

**Script**

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#hideThis").hide();    
  }, 3000);
  pollVisibility();

  function pollVisibility() {
      if (!$("#hideThis").is(":visible")) {
          // call a function here, or do whatever now that the div is not visible
          $("#thenShowThis").show();
      } else {
          setTimeout(pollVisibility, 500);
      }
  }
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id='hideThis' style="display:block">
  The other thing happens when this is no longer visible in about 3s</div>

<div id='thenShowThis' style="display:none">Hi There</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I posted code I based off this above which doesnt seem to be working. I get in the pollVisibility method and inside the else, but the if is never reached.

Comment: is $(".msterWaitBox") selecting an element?  also you should use console.log instead of alert, it makes debugging much easier.

Comment: Yes $(".msterWaitBox") in the console will return the element I am trying to target.

Comment: Actually, it looks like when its not viable. The visibility parameter is not present, and it is moved to a different position on the page. maybe flipping the if/else will work

Comment: No flipping the if else contents and checking if visible pollVis

Comment: instead of testing with `is(":visible")` try checking for the existence of the `visibility` attribute, `if(".mstrWaitBox").attr('visibilty') { ....`  It seems that you are working with some non-standard HTML that is not triggering jquery's filter selectors.

Comment: yeah thats what I was trying. if ($(".mstrWaitBox").attr("visibility")!== 'undefined') || $(".mstrWaitBox").attr("visibility") !== false) { 
      alert('inside if');
           
  }

Answer (score 2):

If your code is running in a modern browser you could always use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) object and fallback on polling with `setInterval` or `setTimeout` when it's not supported.

There seems to be a [polyfill](https://github.com/Polymer/MutationObservers) as well, however I have never tried it and it's the first time I have a look at the project.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bFYQ/)

```
var div = document.getElementById('test'),
    divDisplay = div.style.display,
    observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
        var currentDisplay = div.style.display;

        if (divDisplay !== currentDisplay) {
            console.log('new display is ' + (divDisplay = currentDisplay));
        }
    });

//observe changes
observer.observe(div, { attributes: true });

div.style.display = 'none';

setTimeout(function () {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}, 500);
```

However an even better alternative in my opinion would be to add an interceptor to third-party function that's hiding the div, if possible.

E.g

```
var hideImportantElement = function () {
    //hide logic
};

//intercept
hideImportantElement = (function (fn) {
    return function () {
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('element was hidden');
    };
})(hideImportantElement);
```

Comment: not working for me with Chrome v29.0.1547.76m -- nothing is being output to the console

Comment: @Jason I have the exact same version and it works for me. That's wierd.

Comment: weird, did you update the fiddle and post the pre-updated url?  I'm going here: http://jsfiddle.net/7bFYQ/

Comment: @Jason Version 29.0.1547.76 m - I just clicked the link and it works as expected. My navigator is in french, but that shouldn't change anything technically. Do you get any errors in the console? Does the `MutationObserver` exists?

Answer (score 2):

I used this approach to wait for an element to disappear so I can execute the other functions after that.

Let's say `doTheRestOfTheStuff(parameters)` function should only be called after the element with ID `the_Element_ID` disappears, we can use,

```
var existCondition = setInterval(function() {
 if ($('#the_Element_ID').length <= 0) {
    console.log("Exists!");
    clearInterval(existCondition);
    doTheRestOfTheStuff(parameters);
 }
}, 100); // check every 100ms
```